# Deployed wildfly application using helm chart kubernetes

Tags: docker, wildfly, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

I am facing some issue in wildfly on Administration console dashboard. We used helm chart to deploy wildfly and used bitnami helm charts.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77u76.png)

To access the Administration console you should contact the administrator responsible for WildFly installation and ask him to provide you with the correct address.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here, I was able to reproduce the issue, so I going to create an internal task to investigate more about this. We will update the thread when we have more information.

Comment: I connected pv and pvc but after running service not copy any file in pv location or bitnami/wildfly location.

Comment: i create issue can you check it please